# Find name of ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Does anybody know the name of this equation:
$$\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}r^2} + \frac{1}{r}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}r} - \frac{v^2}{r^2} \right)^2 y = \alpha^4 y $$
I want to solve it numerically and therefore reduce it to a first order system.
To check my answer it would be nice to have a name to find out how it looks like.
Can anybody confirm if this solution is correct?
$\frac{dY(1)}{dr} = Y(2); $
$\frac{dY(2)}{dr} = Y(3); $
$\frac{dY(3)}{dr} = Y(4); $
$\frac{dY(4)}{dr} = Y(5); $
$\frac{dY(5)}{dr} = \alpha^4 Y(1)-\frac{2}{r}Y(4)-2\frac{v^2}{r^2}Y(3)+\frac{1}{r^2}Y(3)-2\frac{v^2}{r^3}Y(2)+\frac{v^4}{r^4}Y(1); $

Comment: This is a linear fourth order ordinary differential equation. If the term on the right was $\frac{\alpha^4}{r^4}y$ instead of $\alpha^4y$, the ODE would be on the Euler kind and easy to solve. Such as it is, I doubt that analytical solving be possible.

Comment: The first two terms come from the Laplacian in polar coordinates, while the third one looks like some kind of potential. Since the terms containing the angular variable are missing, this looks like coming from a problem in polar coordinates where one has attempted separation of variables and this is the radial part of the equation. You may try studying the "square root" of this equation first, maybe it has a better-known name: $\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}r^2} + \frac{1}{r}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}r} - \frac{v^2}{r^2} \right) y = \alpha^2 y$. Or include the full original problem.

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment.
$$
\Delta = \frac{d^2}{dr^2}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{d}{dr} -\frac{v^2}{r^2}
$$
we have
$$
\left(\Delta -\alpha^2\right)\left(\Delta +\alpha^2\right)y = 0
$$
so we have two linear operators which we can try and solve for each case.
we have
$$
\left(\Delta +\alpha^2\right)y_1 = 0\\
\left(\Delta -\alpha^2\right)y_2 = 0.
$$
Try finding the solutions to the last set of equations.